# Duplicate Entry for Key Primary in Django - how do I do an upsert in Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to do an update_or_create on Django, with some logic involved as well (I have to do a slight deviation from best practices with PUT due to the unique nature of the character set I am using).

I've got the following code in my view (only showing the PUT method):

```
class WordView(APIView):

    def put(self, request, user_id):
        character = request.data.get('character')
        correct = request.data.get('correct')
        mistakes = request.data.get('mistakes')
        score = request.data.get('score')

        if Word.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, character=character).exists():
            orig_word = Word.objects.get(user_id=user_id, character=character)
            correct = correct + orig_word.correct
            mistakes = mistakes + orig_word.mistakes
            trials = orig_word.trials + 1
            score = (score + (orig_word.score * orig_word.trials)) / trials
            pk = orig_word.pk
        else:
            trials = 1

        # Note - I know that pk won't exist on create - just testing update right now

        word_saves = {"user_id": user_id, "character": character,
                      "correct": correct, "mistakes": mistakes, "score": score, "trials": trials, "pk": pk}

        serializer = WordSerializer(data=word_saves)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            word_saved = serializer.save()

        return Response({"success": "Word character {} saved for user {}".format(word_saved.character, word_saved.user_id)})
```

Any then in my WordSerializer, I have this:

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    character = serializers.CharField()
    correct = serializers.IntegerField()
    mistakes = serializers.IntegerField()
    score = serializers.FloatField()
    trials = serializers.IntegerField()
    pk = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Word.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data)
```

However, when I make a PUT request when a row with a given user_id and character exist, I get the following:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '29' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

The thing is, I **want** to update the value that exists in the database with my new value. I assumed that that was what `update_or_create` did - an upsert.

How do I do an upsert with the code I currently have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`defaults`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) keyword argument for passing the fields that you want to update when calling [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create). The keyword arguments that you pass other than `defaults` will be used to match the existing record that you want to update.

In your case, if `user_id` and `character` are the unique identifying fields for the model you should just pass these fields as keywords

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Word.objects.update_or_create(
            user_id=validated_data.pop('user_id'),
            character=validated_data.pop('character'),
            defaults=validated_data
        )
```